# Appcompatv7 search widget crashes app

Tags: android, proguard, android-appcompat, android-search

I have implemented Appcompat V7 Search Widget successfully. while Debugging app on phone it shows no problem.(on many phones I tried)
But when I export signed application.
after installing and opening that activity crashes.
Showing error in OnCreateOptionsMenu() method at Search Widget

here is menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/group_search_box"
android:title="@string/search_label"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

And here is how it is implemented.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) 
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.group_search_box);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
```

This was working properly on all phones while debugging but after building apk it is not working.

I think this happens because of proguard.
how can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a proguard-rules.pro file in your module directory.

Add the following to it...

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

res- menu-> actionbar_activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_menu_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
       yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
         yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" >
    </item>
</menu>
```

And the java:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;

private SearchView mSearchView;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_activity_base, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_menu_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        mSearchView.setQueryHint(Html
                .fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'> Search All</font>"));
        // mSearchView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        // / mSearchView.setTextSize(14);
        isClosed = true;
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchString) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("fb", searchString + "submit");

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("fb", arg0 + "change");
                return false;
            }
        });

        mSearchView
                .setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (!hasFocus) {

                            Log.i("fb", "focus chagne");
                            searchItem.collapseActionView();
                            mSearchView.setQuery("", false);



                        }
                    }
                });


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you.. that code is working fine when debugging but same after exporting package.. same activity crashes because of searchwidget

Comment: Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SearchView(Context)

Comment: i think problem in  v7 support library, see do you have add library project if yes that update app v7 library with new and clean and try and see do you import proper package ?

Comment: If there is problem is library then how it works while debugging? I have latest V7 support library

Comment: first clean v7 library project, and rebuild and than try

Answer (score 0):

In menu.xml file in search item just changed  android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" to  app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" and the code workes fine, now search item looks like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_menu"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```